# Problema con code snippet Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un *code snippet* que según la sintaxis está todo bien, pero no logro que el *tab stop* del *snippet* cambie a las variables que están dentro de los paréntesis, al contrario doy clic a *tab*, no hace nada, doy nuevamente clic a *tab* y se mueve a la última variable de sustitución, aquí esta la declaración del *code snippet*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Set de la clase de Negocio</Title>
      <Author>Jorge Torselli</Author>
      <Description>Establece el set modificado para el campo</Description>
      <Shortcut>set</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nombre_set</ID>
          <ToolTip>Escribir el nombre del campo en cuestión</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Tipo_dato</ID>
          <ToolTip>Escribir el tipo de dato en cuestión</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nueva_asignacion</ID>
          <ToolTip>El tipo de dato y nombre que se le asignara</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nombre_campo</ID>
          <ToolTip>EL nombre del campo al que hace referencia = al que se le asigno</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[public void set$Nombre_set$($Tipo_dato$  $Nueva_asignacion$) { this$Nombre_campo$ = $Nueva_asignacion$; }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio Community 2015, al momento de agregar el *snippet* a Visual Studio sigo los pasos que están en el tutorial de MSDN de *code snippets*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado la forma de como resolverlo, hacía falta algunas etiquetas y organizar el código de mejor manera, coloco el código editado y funcional ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>set</Title>
      <Shortcut>set</Shortcut>
      <Description>Fragmento de código para set personalizado</Description>
      <Author>Jorge Torselli</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>nombre</ID>
          <Default>nombre</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre del set</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>tipo</ID>
          <Default>int</Default>
          <ToolTip>Tipo de variable</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>variable</ID>
          <Default>x</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre de variable</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>campo</ID>
          <Default>y</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre de campo</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[Public void set$nombre$ ( $tipo$ $variable$ ) { this$campo$ = $variable$; } $end$]]>
    </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Agregué la etiqueta SnippetType y coloqué dentro de esta Expansion;    esto permite insertar el snippet donde está colocado el cursor, esta clase de     snippet hace que visual studio entienda que el snippet servirá para generar     definiciones de tipos, definiciones de miembros de clases y constructores comunes de código.

Agregué valores default en las variables, para que se tenga que reemplazar el     valor por defecto, que inclusive si se usa un snippet  con un valor que casi            siempre es el mismo se puede agregar dejando la opción para cambiarlo cuando     sea necesario.

Agregué el final $end$ para que el cursor se coloque después de haber expandido el code snippet.

También ordené el código de etiquetas con sangrías según la jerarquía    para mayor facilidad de entendimiento del código.

Este es el link donde encontré la información que acabo de escribir...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379562(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Que bueno que pudiste resolverlo, trate de investigar para resolver esta pregunta, pero no me dio tiempo

Comment: Jorge marca tu respuesta como solución para otros usuarios que la consultemos, gracias